# To pass an interpolated expression into an Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I have seen this question asked few times. But not able to implement the solution mention in those answer in the right way. I am new to Angular and trying to use Observe or watch to pass interpolated expressions into  a custom directive to obtain a one way binding.

I am not sure what is the correct way to use $observe to attain this behavior.

I tried this.

```
attr.$observe('oneway', function (attributeValue) {
                    scope.oneway = scope.$parent.$eval(attributeValue);
                });
```

But found the following issues

1. value in the attribute must not contain {{}} else $eval will
       fail. `<mydir oneway=Prop1></mydir>` will work

   ```
   `<mydir oneway={{Prop1}}></mydir>` fails

    But this will fail my entire objective to  have a one-way binding
   between directive and parent
   ```
2. Even if I have an expression inside the directive, $observe get
           fired only once.  Changing the {{Prop1}} doesn't fire the observe
           function.
3. I tried using $watch instead of $observe. But still facing the same
           issue

What is the  correct way to use observe\watch to obtain a one-way binding between controller and directive ?

Following the complete code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestView</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        function customdir1() {
            var directiveDefinitionObject = {};
            directiveDefinitionObject.templateUrl = "/CustomControl/HtmlPage1.html";
            directiveDefinitionObject.scope = { oneway: "@@oneway" };
            directiveDefinitionObject.link = function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {


                attr.$observe('oneway', function (attributeValue) {

                    scope.oneway = scope.$parent.$eval("Prop1");
                });


            }
            return directiveDefinitionObject;
        }

        var app = angular.module("myapp", []).controller("myCont", function ($scope) {
            $scope.Prop1 = "TestProp1Text";

        }).directive("mydir", customdir1);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myCont">
        {{Prop1}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="Prop1" />
        <mydir oneway={{Prop1}}></mydir>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Markup in the Template (HtmlPage1.html)

```
<b>HII</b>
  {{oneway}}
<input type="text" ng-model="oneway" />
```

Thanks So much in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle of what you need. https://jsfiddle.net/Tsalikidis/eg93q1rc/

```
<mydir oneway="foo"></mydir>
```

and just use '=' to directive's scope

```
...
scope: {
  oneway: '='
}
```

Comment: Thanks So much for the fiddle. But I see a multi directional flow of data.  I have updated the fiddle to demonstrate it.. Could you please check ?  I just need to have a one way flow from Controller to Directive.

Comment: Then just use '@'. I updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Tsalikidis/eg93q1rc/3/ . Just don't use oneway name for the binding variable. I use `x` in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks So much... "Just don't use oneway name for the binding variable." ...Is the solution to the problem.. Is "oneway" a reserved word ?  You can see that even in your fiddle , if you replace x with oneway, it will not work

Comment: Yea, I had no idea either. Maybe there is a angular build-in directive named oneway.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your directive is only supposed to see it's initial value and that's it and never update once the ng-model updates the same scoped parameter, I would suggest [One Time Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) (scroll down to read more)

> An expression that starts with `::` is considered a one-time
>   expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are
>   stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result
>   is a non-undefined value.

Note that the only real difference is in the template of your directive, you're now using the `::` prefix in the expression to tell angular to bind the value and not create any watchers for this particular scoped variable.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eg93q1rc/2/

Javascript:

```
angular
  .module('testApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.Prop1 = 'TestProp1Text';
  }])
  .directive('myDir', function($parse) {
    return {
      scope: {
        oneway: '='
      },
      template: '<span>{{::oneway}}</span>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    };
  });
```

Html

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <my-dir oneway="Prop1"></my-dir>
   <input ng-model="Prop1">
</div>
```

Comment: @gyc yep it's a bit of a hidden one!